# How can I know what changed in a SQL database for a certain time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system to manage printers of a company and I need to understand how the workflow between the Website and database works by knowing what is added/changed in the database with each interaction of the user. Is there a way to find or create some kind of log for a database or even the entire SQL Server that can show me what I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track changes in Microsoft SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872789/track-changes-in-microsoft-sql-server-database)

Comment: That is for DDL, @Sami, I read this as the user means DML. Either way, the *"best"* way to do this (in my opinion) is handle it in the SP's you're using to handle the DML statements.

Comment: It is not easy to accomplished. You should design your data level in such a way. It means to have a track of updates & inserts.

Comment: Sure, have a read of the fine manual, about [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Larnu CDC is DML, no?

Comment: Not sure if you want to track changes to data, the table structures or both?

Comment: Just discovered a tool that does exactly what I need, it is called SQ Server Profiler. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use extended events feature in some case :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are triggers.
You can make tables to log the currently updated or changed data and use triggers to automatically feed data in the log table on any change

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [trigger_name]
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON [table_name] 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN [some condition] 
  DECLARE 
  [variable declaration]
  BEGIN 
     [create an entry in the log table here]
  END;
```

You can use NEW and OLD keywords to refer to the data (new referring to the most recent update of data)

Comment: @Sami sure; i use it currently in two of my productions SQLS systems, but these days I would use a built in facility rather than roll my own

Comment: The question tagged with `SQL Server` tag @CaiusJard which doesn't support `REPLACE` and this code will throw _Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'_ error. It's completely wrong syntax for SQL Server. SQL Server also don't support `FOR EACH ROW` and `ON TABLE_NAME` should be right after the trigger name. Visit **[`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: Eesh.. This is one of the problems with StackOverflow; people are so pedantic. When a question is asked and answered it doesn't mean that the OP has handed complete responsibility for their dev over to a stranger on the internet, who must then provide an absolutely perfect solution considering all contingencies and it's hence reasonable to demand they fix something as inane as "missing semicolon on line 6" -the OP still has ultimate responsibility for the dev, and you're arguing over an aspect of syntax that is navel fluff. It's clear this is pseudocode; remove the `OR REPLACE` and let it go

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm sorry but this was my first time posting an answer, can you please explain why this is not the correct approach?

Comment: Sami's complaint is that you didn't provide a text-perfect solution that the Op can just copypasta and run. My concern is that though it will work, SQL server has this built in so no need to "pollute" an application data domain with triggers and history tables. Most dba generally frown on the use of triggers and the msdn for change tracking is somewhat disparaging of this approach. I don't believe the answer should be downvoted because it isn't necessarily wrong, in the same way that it's not necessarily wrong to use a knife as a screwdriver.. it's just that SQL server has a screwdriver :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Understood! Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, a tool for that exactly purpose exists and is installed together with SQL Server, it is called SQL Server Profiler.